# Issue while reading irregular tab delimited text file into Excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, text-files

I am trying to read a tab delimited text file into an Excel sheet (an initial step to numerous transformation that I have to do). The problem is that the input file is not a clean delimited file. Hence the header ends up in a single cell followed by many lines in single cell but another set of lines get split into multiple columns. Is there a way to clean up the delimiter while reading the file and putting the cleaned up version into worksheet ?

Input sample (the actual file as more columns):

```
    Name    Cost Elem.  Object  Year        Fixed val.      Fixed val.      Fixed val.    

*   RB-001-XXXXXXXXXXX costs    980808  10000003             8,677.89       14,441.99     

*   RB-001-YYYYYYYYYYY costs    980808  10000012            16,116.09       24,757.70     

*   RB-007-ZZZZZZZZZZZ Mgmt &Wrkshop    980204  10000118                 0.03            0.03
```

The notepad++ view of the data and delimiters.

[image]

With help of online forums including stack overflow I managed to assemble the following code.

```
Dim inputfile As String

Sub StartMacro_Click()

inputfile = Range("Sourcepath").Value
MsgBox (inputfile)

Call OpenAndCopyInput

End Sub

Sub OpenAndCopyInput()
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet

    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("datasheet") '<~~ Sheet where you want to import

    Set wbO = Workbooks.Open(inputfile)

i = 1
For Each Row In VBA.Split(wbO, vbCrLf)
    j = 1
    For Each Col In VBA.Split(Row, vbTab)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = Col
        j = j + 1
    Next Col
    i = i + 1
Next Row

End Sub
```

After the import the data looks like this in the worksheet:

[image]

Would be great to have some input to solve this one.

Comment: What do you want to happen?? Do you want the **space** character to be treated like the **tab** during the import ??

Comment: Hi, i am trying to see and hoping that if i can convert multiple consecutive tabs to just a single tab and multiple spaces to a single space it would give  uniformity to data extract before it is written into the worksheet.

Comment: It seems you may have to write a custom function to parse the records.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your function

```
Sub OpenAndCopyInput()
  Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
  Dim wsI As Worksheet

  Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
  Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("datasheet") '<~~ Sheet where you want to import

  With wsI.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & inputfile), _
          Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "NameOfYourFile"  'Just the name without path and file extension
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1) 'For each column you want to import you need a ",1"
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want `Destination:=Range("$A$1")`or `Destination:=wsI.Range("$A$1")` ??